# How to reload a div using render(:update) and replace_html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs, renderpartial

How to reload only the div id on a page?
I just need to reload a certain div.

in my controller I have

```
def mycontrolleraction
 ...

 render(:update) do |page|
   reload_only_the_div('adiv'), :controller => 'my_controller'
 end

end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can replace a div's content with a partial like this.

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html 'person-45', :partial => 'person', :object => @person
end
```

Where the div id is `person-45` the partial's name is `person`. Also you can pass an object to your partial, in this case the object is `@person`. For more information please see the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html).

Comment: Both links are broken now.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz links fixed and deleted, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

ref [ajax-on-rails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-and-ajax.htm) tutorial.To replace the html content of some div use [replace_html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M002195)

```
render :update do |page|
  replace_html 'div', 'new refresh data'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use partials to update particular div in view

```
render :partial => "fileame", :layout => false
```