# Javascript Form Submition

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to refresh the the table "dashboard_categories" when I click submit without the whole page refreshing, this is what I've done so far: http://pastie.org/7822560

I'm now stuck on what I do with Javascript as I'm a complete novice. I know I have to catch the form submission, send the data and then call the partial to refresh... but have no clue how. Any ideas?

Hopefully I'm not far off...

I've got a content_for tag for the javascript on index.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235315/how-to-reload-a-div-using-renderupdate-and-replace-html) may help you.

Comment: What about [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include unobtrusive javascript driver in your manifest `app/assets/javascript/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And then mark the form to be submitted by AJAX:

```
<%= form_for(@category), remote: true do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This is exactly what I was after, just a dumb moment. Now.. how do I go about loading the partial within the div on submit?

Comment: Ok, create.js.erb is rendering correctly. However I need it to reload the div "#dashboard_categories" with the data from create.js.erb?

Comment: I've released create.js.erb is being called and loaded - however it's not rendering with the very latest data? If i submit the form twice, then the second last item shows in the table.

Comment: I've opened a new question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524506/unobtrusive-javascript-not-loading-latest-submitted-data