# Javascript not loading latest submitted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently asked this question: [Javascript Form Submition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463764/javascript-form-submition)?

Now I'm trying to work out why, after form submission, the [create.js.erb](http://pastie.org/7822560) doesn't load the latest data (the data which was submitted).

If I submit the data again, the table will update with the second last data but not the absolute latest.

...why?

**EDIT:**

Latest code -

Categories controller:
    class Admin::CategoriesController < Admin::AdminController
        ...

```
  def create
    @category = Admin::Category.new(params[:admin_category])
    # You can't retrieve the @categories before attempting to add new one. Keep at end of create method.
    @categories = Admin::Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        save_to_history("The category \"#{@category.name}\" has been created", current_user.id)
        format.json { render json: { html: render_to_string(partial: 'categories') } }
        # I've tried both the above and bellow
        #format.json { render json: { html: render_to_string('categories') } }
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_categories_url, :notice => 'Category was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category, :status => :created, :location => @category }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  ...
end
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
      $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**SOLVED**

I used @PinnyM's method and added a create.json.erb file with the following code:

```
<% self.formats = ["html"] %>
{
  "html":"<%= raw escape_javascript( render :partial => 'categories', :content_type => 'text/html') %>"
}
```

and changed my create method to:

```
def create
    @category = Admin::Category.new(params[:admin_category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        # You can't retrieve the @categories before attempting to add new one. Keep after save.
        @categories = Admin::Category.all
        save_to_history("The category \"#{@category.name}\" has been created", current_user.id)
        format.json 
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_categories_url, :notice => 'Category was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category, :status => :created, :location => @category }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Please do offer suggestions if this is messy.

Comment: Can you paste code which you are trying to handle AJAX event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the success callback for your remote (AJAX) submission.  The `data` parameter (2nd argument) holds the response:

```
$(function(){
  $('#new_category').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

A better way to do this (and avoid the dangerous `eval`) might be to just return the partial, and have the callback decide what to do with it:

```
# in create action
format.json { render json: { html: render_to_string('categories') } }

# in your js, run at page load
$(function(){
  $('#new_category').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
    $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Just noticed what @RomanSpiridonov wrote - he's absolutely correct.  You can't retrieve the @categories before attempting to add your new one.  Move the line `@categories = ...` to the end of the `create` method.

Also, I noticed that your Category model is namespaced - that means your default form `id` attribute is more likely something like 'new_admin_category'.  You should check how it is actually being rendered and use that id in your jQuery selector when registering the success callback:

```
$(function(){
  $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function(...
```

Comment: Are you serious? `eval` in an answer to a question, tagged _**unobtrusive JavaScript**_, and assuming jQ when there is no jQ tag?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: was getting to that.  Without `eval` there's no way to have the browser parse the javascript being passed back, which is why I suggest not passing back any javascript.  Regarding jQ - in the linked question, the accepted answer was to use `jquery_ujs` - which requires the use of jQuery.

Comment: Yup, trying to spot the JS in the linked code, I noticed jQ, too. Though I'd hardly classify the OP's intentions as fitting the _unobtrusive JS_ tag... Perhaps best retag this question :)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. So how do I implement this? I've just tried - but maybe I'm missing something? Sorry - you're going to have to hold my hand here, I'm a novice!

Comment: @TaylorWilliams: change your action to use `format.json` instead of `format.js`, register the 'ajax:success' callback in your categories.js file or anywhere on the page (to run after the page loads using `$(function(){...})`), and you can remove the unneeded `create.json.erb`.  If this isn't working for you, perhaps post your revised code - and please post it inline (pastie is great, but not reliable for SO).

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your contribution! I'm now getting this 'Missing template admin/categories/categories, admin/admin/categories, application/categories with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.'. I've tried editing the json render_to_String to '_categories' and 'categories.html.erb' - no prevail. Something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Instance variable @categories in method "create" defined before saving new category. That's why you can't receive the lastest category in your template. 
I think you could write something like that:

`$("#dashboard_categories").append("<%= escape_javascript(render("category")) %>");`

Answer (score 0):

You could add this piece of javascript in a file inside `assets/javascripts` folder

```
$(your_form_selector).on('ajax:success', function(){
  // Read link to see what event names you can use instead of ajax:success and
  // which arguments this function provides you.
})
```

To set `your_form_selector` you could add an id to your form and use `#myFormId`

Read more [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)